# How to vectorise triple for looped cumulative sum

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, cumulative-sum

I want to vectorise the triple sum

\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{m=1}^J a_{ijm}

such that I end up with a matrix

A \in \mathbb{R}^{I \times J}

where A_{kl} = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l\sum_{m=1}^l a_{ijm} for k = 1,...,I and l = 1, ...,J

carrying forward the sums to avoid pointless recomputation.

I currently use this code:
`np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.cumsum(a, axis = 0), axis = 1), axis = 2).diagonal(axis1 = 1, axis2 = 2)`
but it is inefficient as it does lots of extra work and extracts the correct matrix at the end with the diagonal method. I can't think of how to make this faster.

Comment: Latex code is not automatically converted to images on StackOverflow. Please provide the associated image since a raw latex code is hard to read. Alternatively you can provide a pseudocode. Please also provide an estimation of the real-world arrays size and their types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Numba so to produce a very fast implementation. Here is the code:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit('(float64[:,:,::1],)', parallel=True)
def compute(arr):
    ni, nj, nk = arr.shape
    assert nj == nk
    result = np.empty((ni, nj))
    # Parallel cumsum along the axis 1 and 2 + extraction of the diagonal
    for i in nb.prange(ni):
        tmp = np.zeros(nk)
        for j in range(nj):
            for k in range(nk):
                tmp[k] += arr[i, j, k]
            result[i, j] = np.sum(tmp[:j+1])
    # Cumsum along the axis 0
    for i in range(1, ni):
        for k in range(nk):
            result[i, k] += result[i-1, k]
    return result

result = compute(a)
```

---

Here are performance results on my 6-core i5-9600KF with a 100x100x100 float64 input array:

```
Initial code:      12.7 ms
Chryophylaxs v1:    7.1 ms
Chryophylaxs v2:    5.5 ms
Numba:              0.2 ms
```

This implementation is significantly faster than all others. It is about **64 times faster** than the initial implementation. It is also actually **optimal on my machine** since it completely **saturate the bandwidth of my RAM** only for reading the input array (which is mandatory). Note that it is better not to use multiple threads for very small arrays.

Note that this code also use **far less memory** as it only need `8 * nk * num_threads` bytes of temporary storage as opposed to `16 * ni * nj * nk` bytes for the initial solution.

Answer (score 2):

The main challenge here is to compute the inner two sums, i.e. the sum of the square slices of a matrix originating from the top left. The final sum is just a cumsum on top of that along the 0th axis.

Setup:

```
import numpy as np

I, J = 100, 100
arr = np.random.rand(I, J, J)
```

Your implementation:

```
%%timeit
out = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.cumsum(arr, axis = 0), axis = 1), axis = 2).diagonal(axis1 = 1, axis2 = 2)
# 10.9 ms ± 162 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Your implementation improved by taking the diagonal before cumsumming over the 0th axis:

```
%%timeit
out = arr.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=2).diagonal(axis1=1, axis2=2).cumsum(axis=0)
# 6.25 ms ± 34.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Finally, some tril/triu trickery:

```
%%timeit
out = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.tril(arr, k=-1).sum(axis=2) + np.triu(arr).sum(axis=1), axis=1), axis=0)
# 3.15 ms ± 71.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

which is already better, but admittedly still not ideal. I don't see a better way to compute the inner two sums noted above with pure numpy.